# How to let Kubernetes PetSet use existing Persistent Volumes?

Tags: kubernetes

As part of the PetSet definition, the volumeClainTemplates are defined for Kubernetes to dynamically generate Persistent Volume Claims. For example:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 24Gi
```

However, I already has a few of the Persistent Volumes defined:

```
#kubectl get pv    
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                 REASON    AGE 
pv-1-rw   24Gi       RWO           Retain          Bound     rnd/pvc-1-rw             1h
pv-2-rw   24Gi       RWO           Retain          Bound     rnd/pvc-2-rw             6d
pv-3-rw   24Gi       RWO           Retain          Bound     rnd/pvc-3-rw             6d
...
```

I would like the Kubernetes to choose the persistent volumes from the existing ones rather than dynamically creating new ones.

I'm using Kubernetes 1.4.3. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

`volumeClaimTemplates` is an array of `PersistentVolumeClaim`. You can try to define them using `selector` and label existing volumes somehow, i.e.:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv0001
  labels:
    foo: foo
    bar: bar
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv0001/
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv0002
  labels:
    foo: foo
    bar: bar
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv0002/
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
kind: PetSet
apiVersion: apps/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  serviceName: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-slim:0.8
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: html
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: html
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            foo: foo
            bar: bar
```

Of course, volumes must be available for bounding.

```
$ kubectl get pvc html-nginx-0
NAME           STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
html-nginx-0   Bound     pv0002    5Gi        RWO           1m
$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                  REASON    AGE
pv0001    5Gi        RWO           Retain          Available                                    2m
pv0002    5Gi        RWO           Retain          Bound       default/html-nginx-0             2m
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me for k8s v1.4.4. I had to create a PV with a label to be later used for selector in petset. PVCs were created automatically by petset.

Comment: You can also create the PVCs manually so that the volume claim template use them instead of creating new ones. They need to have the same name and `storageClass` than the ones which are automatically created. This technique enable you to manage the mapping between your PVCs and your PVs the way you want.
You can use kind https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/, where dynamic volume provisionning is enabled in order to get the yaml examples for PVs and PVCs. Then adapt PVs to your storage.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to use a select a volume by label

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: data
spec:
    accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
    selector: 
    matchLabels:
        data-label: database-1
```